# Visual Studio 2015 not upgrading 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to use a 2010 project with 2015, not working.

Here is the output file (some names replaced with generic names):

Unsupported

This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.

For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.

- Project Errantry, "C:\Users\BOB\Documents\X TO M conversion\Project Errantry\Project Shadow\Project Shadow\Project Errantry.csproj"

  - Project Errantry GlobalContent, "C:\Users\BOB\Documents\X TO M conversion\Project Errantry\Project Shadow\Project ShadowContent\Project Errantry GlobalContent.contentproj"

    - MapContent, "C:\Users\BOB\Documents\X TO M conversion\Project Errantry\MapContent\MapContent.contentproj"

No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - Project Errantry, "C:\Users\ShyyGuy\Documents\X TO M conversion\Project Errantry\Project Errantry.sln"

I would really like to use visual studio 2015, so any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Since I was using XNA, I realized I needed to install the XNA 4.0 Refresh for Visual Studio 2015. Now converting the project works just fine.

https://mxa.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230